# The leaves on my succulent are getting brown and mushy - help!

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, succulents

I got this succulent from a local florist and have kept in my living room with low light and  regular potting soil. I have have it for about a week - I am just starting to notice the bottom leaves are browning and getting mushy. In touching a bottom leaf, it came off and is mushy on the inside.

What's going on with my succulent? How can I save it!

[image]!

Answer (score 3):

This is a sign of over watering and early root rot let the plant dry out for two weeks. Also remove the squishy leaves and if possible put it in a new pot. The pot you have it in is holding too much water. If you want a good succulent pot get something with plenty of drainage. After 1 week of watering the pot should be bone dry. Forget about it for another week or two then if you feel like it water it. The reason why it only took a week to start developing root rot is because whoever you bought it from designed it that way. They purposefully give pots with poor drainage so the plant dies quicker. So you will then go back and buy another one. The easiest fix however is simply removing it from the ceramic pot. If the distributor is lazy they probably received it directly from the grower and put it in a decorative pot. The grower already has good mix and a good pot lose the decoration and put a plate under it to catch the water dripping out of it. Warning the water will probably smell like sewage and stink if it does let me know. Your local florist probably bought it from a third party distributor. If you really really like the pot and everything never water it in the ceramic pot instead water it outside the pot then once the water has drained **completely meaning no dripping** from the plastic pot put it back inside the ceramic pot.

Cheers

**Good pots**

[https://www.amazon.com/KINGLAKE-Seedlings-Colorful-Container-Starting/dp/B06XK6QJQC/ref=sr_1_9?dchild=1&keywords=flower+pot&qid=1600406231&sr=8-9](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XK6QJQC)